# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axiom/om/util/StAXParserConfiguration in SoapBuilder

Tags: java, soap

Below is my stack trace.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axiom/om/util/StAXParserConfiguration
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:108)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:354)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
```

Comment: The classes were available at build time. But are not available at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to bundle the missing library with your deployed artifact,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit searching found that, the dependencies in my project for org.apache.axis2 were been upgraded from 1.5.1 to 1.5.3.
After 1.5.1 version had a transitive dependency on the library having the StAXParserConfiguration class. 
But the later(newer) one does not have it. As such, I have to add the artifact explicitly in my pom.